# Difference between SMS and Network SMS

Tags: mobile, sms, mobile-phones, network-protocols

I need to know the difference between one simple SMS and one Network SMS?

Comment: What do you mean by "Network SMS"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are *just guesses* but would need to know the context to give a proper answer.

- Could mean the difference between an
  SMS that is sent cross-network, from
  one mobile phone provider's network
  to another one.  So a 'simple' SMS
  stays within the one network.
- If the SMS is sent from the mobile
  phone provider to multiple phones 
  eg. a special offer, marketing type
  blurbs... that is sometimes referred
  to as a network SMS, though I
  wouldn't consider it a standard piece
  of terminology.